# Redirection - from one account to two via canonical

Tags: postfix

On a handful of servers in my environment I've got the following in /etc/postfix/canonical:

```
if !/DoNotReplyA@example.com/i
/.+/ generic@example.com
fi
```

Now I'm being asked to do add another email to ignore from getting converted. From what I understand I can't do a simple:

```
if !/DoNotReply[AB]@example.com/i
```

I'm tempted to do a:

```
if !/DoNotReply(.*)@example.com/i
```

to handle any case they might come up with in the future but that's more wide open and would accept anything that starts with "DoNotReply" in it.

I've seen mention of updating /etc/postfix/virtual with something like:

```
DoNotReplyA@example.com   DoNotReplyA@example.com
DoNotReplyB@example.com   DoNotReplyB@example.com
```

and then in the canonical maybe have a line like:

```
/.+/ generic@example.com
```

but not sure of the order of processing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to instead entirely eradicate anything called "do not reply". It is about as appropriate as walking up to peoples doors, ringing the bell and ditching.